# What is qualitative effect of multimode laser source used with diffractive optical elements designed for single mode source?

Tags: optics

Suppose I am generating a light pattern using off-the-shelf diffractive optics elements and a single mode laser diode.  For specificity let's assume the laser diode is operating at 532 nm and the pattern is a regular, 40 x 40 pattern of 'dots' covering a 30 degree by 30 degree field.  Suppose now that I swap out the single mode laser source for a higher power multimode laser diode source operating at the same wavelength of 532 nm.  Assuming I take the requisite amount of care to make sure things align correctly and so on, what would you expect the effect of this swap to be on the generated pattern?

For example: Should I expect the dots to be elongated in one or more dimensions?  Will the projected pattern now depend on distance in some surprising way?  Is the result totally unpredictable?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best guess.
Diffraction primarily depends on the factor λ/D, where 
λ - wavelength of light
D - aperture dimension

In your case, both of these remain same and as the output is from a laser, it's essentially a parallel beam( with minimal divergence). Hence I wouldn't expect the pattern to be different from that of a single mode laser. The intensity distribution can however be different, as the laser is now emitting more power.

Answer (score -1):

Original answer:

> Si solo cambia la potencia el patrón debe ser el mismo

Free translation:

> Only the power changes, the pattern should be the same.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE! This answer would benefit a lot from some elaboration $-$ as it stands, it's simply an statement, without any explanation or even a link.

Comment: Also, Zxy, following [this policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/70/75633) I've translated your answer to English. Thanks for your contribution, but if you can read enough of the language to answer the question, I'd recommend you try to write your answer also in English $-$ even bad English will reach a broader audience here than Spanish.